# Different z values after adjusting the p values with post-hoc analysis?

Tags: r, z-score

I met a problem in interpreting z values in my GLMM and its post-hoc tests. Since what I am calculating is the counts, I used the poisson family from glmer. and I got a z values of z value = 2.278. But after I put the model into post-hoc analysis ("Dunn" adjustment) with "emmeans", the z value became z value = -3.350. Why would the z value change? I'm concerned about the reliability of the results. If the two are different, which value shall I trust?
The code in the model runs like this: summary(m1 <- glmer(y ~ fixed1*fixed2+(1|random1)+(1|random2), family="poisson", data=data,control=glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))). Fixed1 represents for fixed factor one, fixed2 for fixed factor 2, random1 for random factor 1, and random2 for random factor 2. While for the post-hoc analysis, I used: pairs(emmeans(m1, pairwise~fixed1),adjust="Dunn"), in order to adjust p value. But the z values are different from the two. So how shall I interpret the results? Thanks!